# Automate input procedure to a binary file

Tags: scripting, input

I have a binary file on Unix, which when executed asks the user for inputs. The inputs to this binary file are given manually. I want to automate the procedure, since I know the inputs already. I can't modify the binary file. How can I do this ? Is this possible via shell script or even with `ant` targets ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the program reads from standard input (as opposed to direct from the terminal), you could do something like

```
echo -e "answer1\nanswer2\nanswer3\n" | your_program
```

A [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) may be more readable:

```
your_program <<'EOF'
answer1
answer2
answer3
EOF
do_more_stuff
```

(You can pick any string instead of `EOF`, just make sure to use the same in `<<'somestring'` and to mark the end of the input. The string must not appear as an input line. The end-of-input mark must not be indented.)

If you need more complex interaction then an `expect` script is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you have many inputs, you can also put these inputs into a file

```
in.txt:
input1
input2
...
intputn
```

And call binary like this :

```
binary < in.txt
```